# Java class property that can support different types

Tags: java, types

I am building a content management system with Java, I have a class to express an Entity, and a class to express a Field within the Entity.

Currently my Field class as an array list of String to store all of the values.

My class looks like this:

```
public class Field implements Serializable {
    private UUID key;
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<String> values;
    private Integer maxValues;
    private ValueType type;
    private String code;

    public enum ValueType {
        INT,
        VARCHAR,
        DATE,
        BOOLEAN
    }

    public void addValue(String value){
        if (this.values.size() < this.maxValues){
            this.values.add(value);
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getValues(){
        return this.values;
    }
}
```

I would like to store String, Integer, Floats and Dates, I am thinking I could type check the values when they are entered and have separate methods for getting the values as the correct types.

```
public ArrayList<Integer> getIntegerValues(){

    ArrayList<Integer> integerValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();


    values.forEach(
        (v) -> {

            Integer intValue = Integer.parseInt(v);

            integerValues.add(intValue);

        }
    );

    return integerValues;
}
```

I figure this would work but it does not feel like a great solution, as when using this class you would have to select the correct function to get the types. It would be good if there was just a single function to return the correct version.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can write this better.

Comment: Looks like you want to use generics

Comment: Can a single field contains more than one types?

Comment: No a field would never contain different types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not 100% happy with either answer, neither felt like the right way to solve this issue, both ways had issues to deal with. However I realised that both answers together will give a nice solution, so thanks to both.

Your concrete class will define the values for the generic value. This will satisfy the open closed principal.

```
public interface FieldType<T> {
    void addValue(T value);
    ArrayList<T> getValues();
}

public abstract class Field<T> implements FieldType<T>, Serializable {
    private UUID key;
    private String name;
    protected ArrayList<T> values;
    private Integer maxValues;
    private String code;

    public abstract void addValues();

    public ArrayList<T> getValues(){
        return this.values;
    }
}

public class FloatField extends Field<Float> {

    @Override
    public void addValue(Float value) {
        this.values.add(value);
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList<Float> getValues() {
        return this.values;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you could use generics:

```
public class Field<T> implements Serializable {
    private UUID key;
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<T> values;
    private Integer maxValues;
    private String code;

    public void addValue(T value) {
        if (this.values.size() < this.maxValues){
            this.values.add(value);
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<T> getValues(){
        return this.values;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this idea, I think it would solve my problems but at the same time introduce another issue of not knowing the type when returning this, I think I will implement strict type checking when adding values to a field to correspond to the object type.

Comment: You should know the type.  When you define a Field, you will define it as Field<Type> and whatever Type you put there will be the type that's returned.

Answer (score 1):

More as another point of view: should you come to the conclusion that generics won't help you here - you should still **not** use an enum for such kind of things.

The problem with enums is: they are pretty helpful for "models" that have a very small chance of being changed in the future. Because what typically happens is: for each enum that you have, you will be creating **switch** statements; in order to implement different behavior for your different enum constants. That may not sound like a problem, but it is ... when you realize that you need to add **another** type. Then you have to find all those switches and decide how to handle the new enum constant.

Instead, your design should be driven by the [Open/Closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle): being **open** for changes; but **closed** for modification. In OO, that most often translates into using abstract classes, like

```
public abstract class ValueType {
  ... which has some ABSTRACT methods
  ... and probably some FINAL methods
```

The abstract methods is where you implement that behavior that should be different for the various child classes; and the FINAL methods are those that "fix" that behavior, that should be the same for each any instance of this classes.

And then you go forward and create specific subclasses, like `IntValue extends ValueType` and so on.

And why is that better? Very simple: adding a new kind of ValueType means ... creating a new subclass - without the need to touch any existing code. Thus such a design is **open** for change (adding new types!), but **closed** for modification (as adding a new type doesnt change anything in other existing classes).

Comment: I quite like this idea, would be able to force a ValueType to be added in the constructor, but if the abstract method addValue and getValue would need to use generics ?

Comment: Although I have checked the generics answer is correct, I have written the code for the generics implementation and I am not finding it to be the best solution, it violates the open closed principal as you mentioned, I think the abstraction may be required on the Field class, so would have a VarcharField / IntegerField / FloatField extends Field, will try the implementation out and see how that feels, but in my mind it seems like it would offer more flexibility in the design, easier to add new types.

Comment: I am glad you find my input helpful. If possible, I would recommend you to talk to some experienced folks face to face; such problems simply need a lot of thinking; and exchange of ideas often helps.